# How to compare two list elements?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have two list

```
<cfset thelist1 = valueList(Gettest.full_name) /> 
<cfset thelist2 =ReplaceNoCase(colorList2,".jpg","","all")>

thelist1 =(test1,test2,test3,test4,test5)
thelist2 = (test1,test3)
```

How can I compare thelist1 to thelist2 and get the elements that are not in thelist2 from thelist1?

I was thinking maybe to get the list that is not on thelist2 I have to create another thelist3.

Comment: Do u want to add the items in list2 that are there in list1 but not in list2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use some java methods to do that. Here is what I do:

```
<cfset theArray1 = listToArray(thelist1)>
<cfset theArray2= listToArray(thelist2)>
```

Now if I want to retain matching items, then I would do something like this:

```
<cfset theArray1.retainAll(theArray2) />
```

And if I want to remove the matching items, then some thing like this:

```
<cfset thearray1.removeAll(theArrar2) />
```

Then finally I would convert the array to a list (if it is required) .

Note `removeAll` and `retainAll` are java methods, but work fine in ColdFusion and you don't even need to import the java library or package.

Comment: `retainAll()` and `removeAll()` will be case sensitive correct?

Comment: Yes it's case sensitive. If you want to make it case insensitive then one can use toUppercase or toLowercase method and then convert list into an array

Comment: There's a few UDFs on cflib.org that can do this as wel Keshav. like this one - http://cflib.org/udf/ListInCommon.

Comment: Yes I agree. Both way u can do this. I found above solution bit nicer as it has less and clean code. And everything is taken care by java itself.

Comment: certainly looks it. I'll have to play around with it. Case could be an issue for some folks though.

Comment: I love that java functions work seamlessly with Coldfusion, makes thing so much easier. Great answer @Keshavjha

Comment: I agree with Anurag. Those are really great functions to use especially in case of performing set intersection and subtraction respectively.

Comment: My 2 cents - just found this now and what a great elegant solution by @Keshav jah

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use closures and standard list functions to generate a list (or array) of all elements contained in the first list, but *not* the second:

```
resultArray = [];
listEach(firstList, function(value, index) {
    if (!listFindNoCase(secondList, value)) {
        arrayAppend(resultArray, value);
    }
});
```

Having said that, it looks like the source of the first list is a database query. If the second list of items is relatively small, this could also be done within your database query. Simply use a `WHERE NOT IN (...)` clause to retrieve all values that are *not* contained in the supplied list. Something like this:

```
QueryExecute("SELECT full_name FROM yourTable WHERE full_name NOT IN ( :filterList )"
    , { filterList={ value=secondList, cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR", list="true"} }
);
```

Comment: Thats just perfect!

Answer (score 2):

The **NewList** variable will have the *List1* elements that are not in *List2*

```
<cfset thelist1 = "test1,test2,test3,test4,test5">
<cfset thelist2 = "test1,test3">

<cfset NewList = ListRemoveDuplicates(thelist1)>

<cfloop list="#thelist2#" index="i">
    <cfif listFindNoCase(NewList, i)>
         <cfset NewList = listdeleteat(NewList,listFindNoCase(NewList, i))>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#NewList#" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a nested loop inside of another loop.

```
<cfscript>
    theList1 = listToArray("1,2,3");
    theList2 = listToArray("2,3");
    notInList = "";
    for ( i=1 ; i<=arrayLen(theList1) ; i++ ) {
        itemFound = false;
        for ( ii=1 ; ii<=arrayLen(theList2) ; ii++ ) {
            if( theList1[i] EQ theList2[ii] ) {
                itemFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( !itemFound ){
            notInList = listAppend(notInList,theList1[i]);
        }
    }
</cfscript>
```

You'll find the items in theList1 that are not in theList2

Comment: Why are you converting your lists to arrays?

Comment: @DanBracuk for scale, at bigger scale, arrays are faster than list operations, also cleaner to address in code using associative arrays than using listGetAt for every iteration.

Comment: (Edit) *arrays are faster than list operations* Not always. It depends on the application. For example, with even 500 items, the code above is significantly slower than the other two methods suggested or using a single loop and listFindNoCase ie Very quick test - 1139 ms versus 15 ms. Granted, a good portion of the extra time is due to using a nested loop. However, point is that simply using arrays does not mean code will run faster. It depends on the code.  Though agreed listGetAt is a bit ugly compared to array notation.

Comment: @leigh like I said, AT SCALE, array operations are faster than lists. You compared nested loops to single loops with functions, if you did the same comparison to test array functions vs list functions, you'd see that there's a clear breakpoint in scale where arrays start edging lists and then exponentially outperform them as you grow. Yes, at small scale, list functions will be marginally faster than arrays, but not if you're hoping to scale your application.

Comment: But you're right, I should have used arrayFindNoCase() instead of the nested loop, that would've been faster.

Comment: I understood what you meant, but mentioning "at scale" following an example using nested looping seemed a bit ... incongruous ;-) *used arrayFindNoCase() instead* Yes, better than nested loops. Though surprisingly I found the performance a bit poorer than I had expected in normal usage.

Answer (score 0):

**function fLvL** to return an array `[onlyInFirst, onlyInSecond, inBoth]`:

```
<cffunction name="fLvL" hint="function List vs List: returns array[listOnlyInFirst, listOnlyInSecond, listInBoth]">
    <cfargument name="argL1" default="">
    <cfargument name="argL2" default="">
    <cfargument name="argDelim" default=",">
    <cfargument name="argDedup" default="1" hint="boolean 0/1 for Y/N, also will work w true/false">
    <cfargument name="argSort" default="0" hint="boolean 0/1 for Y/N, also will work w true/false">
    <cfargument name="argSortType" default="textNoCase" hint="others: numeric, text (case sens), aabzABZ, aAaBbBzzZ">

    <cfset var raRet=["","",""]>
    <cfif !len(argL1)>
        <CFRETURN ["", argL2, ""]>
    <cfelseif !len(argL2)>
        <CFRETURN [argL1, "", ""]>
    </cfif>
    <cfloop index="iL1item" list="#argL1#">
        <cfif listFindNoCase(argL2, iL1item, argDelim)>
            <cfset raRet[3] = listAppend(raRet[3], iL1item, argDelim)>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset raRet[1] = listAppend(raRet[1], iL1item, argDelim)>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfloop index="iL2item" list="#argL2#">
        <cfif !listFindNoCase(argL1, iL2item, argDelim)>
            <cfset raRet[2] = listAppend(raRet[2], iL2item, argDelim)>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfif argSort>
        <cfloop index="iCnt" from="1" to="3">
            <cfset reRet[iCnt] = listSort(reRet[iCnt], argSortType, argDelim)>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    <cfif argDedup>
        <cfloop index="iCnt" from="1" to="3">
            <cfset reRet[iCnt] = listRemoveDuplicates(reRet[iCnt], argDelim)>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn raRet>
</cffunction>

<cfset raResult=fLvL("first,list","second,list")>
<cfdump var="#raResult#">
<!--- returns: ["first","second","list"] --->
```

`raResult=fLvL("first,list","second,list")`
returns array:
`["first","second","list"]`

Also gives some further argument options (probably overkill).